# How does SE select which questions to be shared in Twitter?

Tags: discussion

I follow Sceptics SE twitter account, Some questions are shared in Twitter Feed. How are they chosen? Do you think shared questions increase traffic and user engagement enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are they chosen?

Here is one answer: [How does the twitter bot work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183410/139866)